# What are the higher order derivatives of the logistic function?

Tags: derivatives

What are the higher order derivatives of the logistic function

$$\sigma(x) = \frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}$$

and is there a general formula for them?

Comment: It helps to notice that $\sigma'(x) = \sigma(x)(1 - \sigma(x))$.

Answer (score 1):

This holds for $n \in \{0, 1, 2\}$, but a counterexample is $n=3$.

By the statement, we should have

$$F’’’ = F(1-F)(1-2F)(1-3F).$$

However, we have

\begin{align*}
F’’’ &= [F(1-F)(1-2F)]’ \\
&= F(1-F)^2(1-2F) - F^2(1-F)(1-2F)-2F^2(1-F)^2 \\
&= F(1-F)(1-2F)[(1-F) - F - \frac{2F(1-F)}{1-2F}] \\
&= F(1-F)(1-2F)[1-3F + F - \frac{2F(1-F)}{1-2F}] \\
&= F(1-F)(1-2F)[1-3F - \frac{F}{1-2F}]
\end{align*}
which is a contradiction.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/2009650)

Answer (score 1):

For the $n$'th derivative of the logistic function, we can derive formulas that are recursive, a series, or explicit in terms of a special function.

For the recursive formula, use, as in **@littleO's** hint in the comments, that the logistic function satisfies $\sigma'=\sigma(1-\sigma)$ and apply to that the generalized Leibniz (product rule) formula. Hence, $$\sigma^{(n+1)}=\sigma^{(n)}(1-\sigma)-\sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\sigma^{\left(n-k\right)} \sigma^{\left(k\right)}$$

For a general formula, we may observe by the geometric series formula that $\displaystyle\sigma(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\left(-e^{-x}\right)^{i}$, for positive $x$, which can be termwise differentiated very easily to $\displaystyle\sigma^{(n)}(x)=(-1)^{n}\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}i^n\left(-e^{-x}\right)^{i}$. This series alone provides a good approximation to $\sigma^{(n)}$ for large positive $x$, but also allows writing the derivative explicitly in terms of the special function, the [Lerch Transcendent](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LerchTranscendent.html)

$$\sigma^{(n)}=(-1)^{n}\Phi(-e^{-x},-n,0)$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $$\sigma^{(n)}=\sigma\sum_{k=0}^{n}L(n,k)\sigma^k$$
and $L(n,k)=0$ when $k\notin [0,n]$. We have the recursion
$$L(n+1,k)=(k+1)L(n,k)-kL(n,k-1)$$
First values are easy to find: $L(n,0)=1$, $L(n,1)=1-2^n$. Are they connected with some kind of Stirling
numbers?

Comment: I think there may be an error in your recursion formula as it simplifies to $(k+1)L-kL=(k+1-k)L=L$.

Comment: @Jam Thanks. I hope it is correct now. I threw my paper work away.